# Change an existing C source file to 80 column width in Vim

Tags: vim, coding-style, indentation

I have several C files, in which the lines exceed more than 80 columns. I need to wrap them to a 80 column boundary and at the same time maintain proper C syntax. Is this possible in Vim?

I have seen several solutions on the web for doing it on a normal text file. Also, have found tricks to do wrapping in a C file, which is about to be edited. But not for existing C files.

Any tools for achieving this apart from Vim are also welcome.

Comment: Judging by your previous question, I must ask: are you sure you *need* that? Books may tell you that you *should* do this or that but it doesn't mean you *must*. Your company having established such a standard is a good reason but your program won't break or have poorer performance if you write 120 characters lines. As with the newline, that 80 char "standard" was dictated decades ago by physical limitations that don't really matter today. Unless you only use tools like `read` or `cat` on an 80 columns terminal window.

Comment: The coding guide line in my company needs that, even though I have a wide screen monitor! Also, some of the source code will be part of the Linux kernel, where it is mandatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you edit c-sources it is likely that you set the cindent option. Unfortunately the textwidth option doesn't work with cindent.

For your purpose artistic style, although it's a very nice program isn't recommended either since it doesn't support the breaking of long lines.

To get what you want i use gnu indent and set equalprg to

```
let &equalprg= "indent -l80 -i" . &shiftwidth . " <optional args>"
```

and add

```
map <leader>i mzgg=G`z
```

to my `~/.vimrc`. With that pressing `<leader>i` reformats the whole file without changing the cursor's position.

Another possibility would be to add an autocommand that indents the source on every write, like

```
autocmd BufWrite *.c execute "%!".&equalprg
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked for majority of my C source code. It did not work on comments, long strings and #defines. Can live with it for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

With vim you could do that with `:set tw=79` and `gggqG`. However, it is not context-aware so you will need to restore certain lines (for example, lines with long strings in them).

For an external tool you might want to look at [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/), which reformat lines where reformatting is not hard (for example, lines containing a `{`).

Comment: As a side note, I would add that if you have multiple branches on your current project, it will become much harder to merge development happening in different branches. So that kind of modification should be done at well thought time.